# Vue/Element-Plus: Use variable in sub-component

Tags: vuejs3, element

I'm using element-plus and want to embed a tree into a timeline.
I'm using the timeline component as the template: https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/timeline.html#custom-timestamp
And here's my code:

```
<el-timeline>
    <el-timeline-item
      v-for="(job, index) in jobList"
      :key="index"
      :timestamp="job.job_name"
    >
      <el-tree **:data="job"** :props="defaultProps" @node-click="handleNodeClick" />
  </el-timeline-item>
  </el-timeline>
```

So I'm trying to pass the "job" in the v-for to the sub-component el-tree inside this el-timeline-item but it didn't work. I got the first item of the el-timeline-item then an empty tree.

Can you please advise how do I pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value that you provide to the `data` prop of the tree component must be of type Array - not an Object.